# Prove the following sequence diverges: $\sqrt{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}+4$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am trying to work through proving some sequences diverge. I am having a really hard time with the inequality arguments and I'm not sure why. The current problem is proving that $$\sqrt{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}+4$$ diverges to infinity.

I understand that essentially I let $c$ be an arbitrary positive number and then I have to find some natural number $N$ dependent on $c$ so that $$\sqrt{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}+4>c$$ for all $n\geq N$. The trouble I have is sussing out what $N$ needs to be for an arbitrary chosen $c$.

Comment: Let's say c=100. Can you find N for this c? (you don't even need to find the best possible N, just any N.)

Comment: $\sqrt{n} - \frac{1}{n^2} +4 > \sqrt{n} -1 +4 = \sqrt{n} +3 > \sqrt{n}$ and try what you did before .

Comment: Thank you. you are right in not needing to find the best possible $N$. That is definitely where I hit a mental block sometimes.

Comment: Hello Christian, may I ask what book/source are you getting your questions from? I'd like to refer to it as well.

Comment: This question came from Advanced Calculus second edition by Patrick M. Fitzpatrick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that I got it thanks to dem0nakos comment about not needing the best possible $N$.

Proof:
Let $c$ be any positive number. By the Archimedean property we can select a natural number $N_1$ so that $N_1>4c^2$ and therefore $\sqrt{N_1}>2c$. Simultaneously we can find an $N_2$ such that $\frac{1}{N_2^2}<c$. If we let $N=\max\{N_1,N_2\}$ and take $n\geq N$ then we have
$$\sqrt{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}+4>\sqrt{4c^2}-\frac{1}{n^2}+4=2c-c+4=c+4>c$$ as desired.